# jQuery onchnage function call in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, jquery

How to use custom js in Magento 2.3 add jquery

```
jQuery('.customdrop select').on('change',function(){
    console.log(jQuery('.customdrop select').find(":selected").text));
    if (jQuery('.customdrop select').find(":selected").text() === 'Other'){
        jQuery('.customfields').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('.customfields').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: which custom js you are using here? I can see only jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery using requirejs as below.

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $('.customdrop select').on('change',function(){
        console.log($('.customdrop select').find(":selected").text));
        if ($('.customdrop select').find(":selected").text()==='Other'){
            $('.customfields').show();
        } else {
            $('.customfields').hide();
        }
    });        
});
```

You can include the above code in your phtml file or in your custom js and include it using layouts.